# How to search for documentation in Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

I am using eclipse/sts. In one big project I need to search for all the method and class documentations. When I use "Search"->"File.." and when I try "/**" it isn't finding what I need. Please help me, how can I search for the doc.

Comment: Have you actually tried 'Help > Help Contents'?

Comment: yes but cant find an answer there

Comment: @greg-449 do you know the answer or you are just sending me to the check the whole doc for something that is not there?

Comment: I don't use STS so I can say for sure, but most Eclipse add-ons add a section to the help which includes the Javadoc.

Comment: which option are you putting "/**" into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*` character has a special meaning in the eclipse file search. You should escape it with a `\` as such : `/\*\*`